# What would you use to build a distributed database with client?

Tags: database, distributed, bittorrent, libtorrent

if I wanted to create a distributed database for media files (say, images), what would I use?

The idea is that the DB wouldn't be controllable by any particular entity (though the software would be, though it's GPL / forkable).

Instead, you'd have a client which has something like libtorrent and can be used to browse / cache the database.   You'd configure the client with a list of 'sources'.

Cydia is a good model for this.

Though instead of using web hosts, I'd like to use bit torrent seeders that act as super nodes (which would catalog sub nodes of arbitrary tree height)

Would libtorrent be the best way to go?  Or would there be a better alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Just because there exist seeders for a given torrent doesn't mean *your* client is aware of what they are seeding. You would need at least a magnet link, or a torrent file for each separate "thing".

So, "caching" content with torrent, ok, but as far as "browsing" is concerned, you need something else (eg: an index, that would list magnet/torrent files - and I doubt you would build that using lib/bittorrent...).

Secondly, your list of "sources" would be provided by a tracker in order to connect to your swarm, or at least a list of known peers (supernodes as you call them) if using DHT - yet again provided by something else that libtorrent.

Also, obviously (?) you can't "update" content with torrent - if something "changes", then it's a different torrent - so, short term, you would have a database with items that can't be modified... "replicated" over bittorrent, but indexed by some other technology.

I don't quite understand why you are looking at bittorrent to (re)implement a "distributed database", but this seems ill-formed to me (if only, because of the index, that wouldn't be distributed, pretty much defeating the purpose).

If your problem is reliability / scalability, why not consider any (existing) "db" engine that would natively do the job? (replica sets with mongo, or distributed filesystem on hadoop, or even good old-school handmade data replication between nodes, or even sql master slaves, or some cloud storage...).

If your problem is "ownership" over the database, yet again it's not about the content, it's about the index.
Now, I can imagine something where peers would exchange lists of items they own between them, allowing a given peer to get data from another given one, but this is quite far away from what I would call a "database"...

I don't think you can let-go "ownership" (at least over the index) without letting go the concept of "database"... (assuming I understood well what you meant by "the DB wouldn't be controllable by any particular entity")

Comment: I'm looking at refuge.io at the moment

Comment: Refuge uses CouchDB as its core storage IIRC.Now, Refuge is not a database, much more a sharing platform, right?